# Can JCA resource adapter works in Weblogic without SOA server running?

Tags: ejb, weblogic, soa, adapter

I am trying to deploy Oracle JCA file adapter into Weblogic to access native file system from my message driven bean.  After installing SOA suite, I can find the adapters' RAR files in the SOA HOME/soa/connectors directory.

Since I don't have database installed, my SOA server can not be launched.  But I can still create a Weblogic domain with SOA supported, after launching that domain (with some errors), I can see the file adapter is "correctly" deployed.

So I wonder if the JCA resource adapter can work without SOA server?  I am asking because I met a very [strange issue during the deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253774/weblogic-could-not-find-resource-adapter-with-correct-jndi-name-for-binding), and I doubt it might related to the lack of SOA server running.

If SOA server is not mandatory for using resource adapter, what is the minimum dependency to deploy a file adapter into Weblogic?

Any idea is appreciated, thanks in advanced.